# Issue with parsing JSON in Angular 1.6.9

Tags: angularjs, json

I am pretty new to angular and i am running into an issue displaying JSON data with the ng-repeat tag in my JSP.
Here's my code,
I am fetching data from an external REST service and it is sending me the JSON which is well formatted.
Here's the sample JSON,

```
 {"products":[
  {
     "description":"E-Series Util",
     "effectiveEndDate":"2099-04-20",
     "effectiveStartDate":"2018-04-20",
     "id":"2c92c0f962e1d5af0162e698b14b6520",
     "name":"NOD-E-series-Utilities",
     "productFeatures":[

     ],
     "productRatePlans":[
        {
           "description":"",
           "effectiveEndDate":"2025-04-20",
           "effectiveStartDate":"2018-04-20",
           "id":"2c92c0f862e1caed0162e699ffc922e6",
           "name":"NOD-E series-Utilities",
           "productRatePlanCharges":[
              {
                 "billingDay":"SpecificDayofMonth/1st of the month",
                 "billingPeriod":"Month",
                 "billingPeriodAlignment":"AlignToCharge",
                 "description":"",
                 "endDateCondition":"Subscription_End",
                 "financeInformation":{
                    "deferredRevenueAccountingCode":"",
                    "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode":""
                 },
                 "id":"2c92c0f962e1d5af0162e6a313cc752d",
                 "model":"PerUnit",
                 "name":"NOD-E Series-Utilities-NR",
                 "pricing":[
                    {
                       "currency":"USD",
                       "price":"0E-9"
                    }
                 ],
                 "pricingSummary":[
                    "USD0/NR"
                 ],
                 "ratingGroup":"ByBillingPeriod",
                 "revenueRecognitionRuleName":"Recognize upon invoicing",
                 "taxCode":"",
                 "taxable":false,
                 "triggerEvent":"ContractEffective",
                 "type":"Usage",
                 "uom":"NR",
                 "usageRecordRatingOption":"EndOfBillingPeriod",
                 "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange":true
              },
              {
                 "billingDay":"SpecificDayofMonth/1st of the month",
                 "billingPeriod":"Month",
                 "billingPeriodAlignment":"AlignToCharge",
                 "description":"",
                 "endDateCondition":"Subscription_End",
                 "financeInformation":{
                    "deferredRevenueAccountingCode":"",
                    "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode":""
                 },
                 "id":"2c92c0f862e1caed0162e6a0cb842eab",
                 "model":"PerUnit",
                 "name":"NOD-E Series-Utilities-Usage",
                 "pricing":[
                    {
                       "currency":"USD",
                       "price":"0.100000000"
                    }
                 ],
                 "pricingSummary":[
                    "USD0.1/GB"
                 ],
                 "ratingGroup":"ByBillingPeriod",
                 "revenueRecognitionRuleName":"Recognize upon invoicing",
                 "taxCode":"",
                 "taxable":false,
                 "triggerEvent":"ContractEffective",
                 "type":"Usage",
                 "uom":"GB",
                 "usageRecordRatingOption":"EndOfBillingPeriod",
                 "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange":true
              }
           ],
           "status":"Active"
        }
     ],
     "sku":"SKU-00000020"
  }
  }
```

Here's my HTML snippet

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="a in products">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-8 lead "><strong>{{a.name}}</strong></td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                        <button id="view_btn" class="btn btn-sm prospect-color"
                        ng-click="showplan = ! showplan"
                        >View Plans</button>

                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                <button id="add_cart_btn" class="btn btn-sm prospect-color"
                        ng-click="addItemToCart(a)"
                        >Add to Cart</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="col">

                        <div class="card card body" ng-show="showplan" ng-repeat="r in a.productRatePlans" >
                        <strong>{{a.description}} with SKU # - {{r.name}} </strong> {{a.sku}}</div>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my JS file,

```
$http({ 
          method: 'GET',
          url:'/WebStoreSMP/rest/products/', 
 }).then(function (response)
         { 
    // var obj = JSON.parse(response); 
     $scope.products = angular.fromJson(response);
     console.log("[main] # of items: " + JSON.stringify(response))

   },function (error){ 
       alert("AJAX failed to get data for product, status=" + error);  
  });
```

The issue is that i am not seeing any data on the HTML page.
The console log is printing the entire JSON response.
Any idea what might be wrong here?
Thanks,
VK

Comment: response if an HTTP response. You want the body of the response, that Angular parses for you: `$scope.products = response.data.products;`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns

Comment: Cool...that worked...Thanks!!!!